# Unable to set attributes on PHP soapvar

Tags: php, soap-client

This question has been asked many times, but there is no convincing answer yet. I am trying to generate xml that looks like this:

```
<parameters>
   <createUser version='3.0'>
      <name>Batman</name>
   </createUser>
</parameters>
```

My code is:

```
$createUser = new \stdClass();
$createUser->version = '3.0';
$createUser->name = 'Batman';
$parameters->createUser = new \SoapVar($createUser, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$soapRequest = new \SoapVar($parameters,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 
    NULL, $typeNamespace, 'createUser');

$response = $soapClient->__soapCall('submit', 
    array('parameters' => $soapRequest));
```

And the response I get, of course, is:

```
<parameters>
   <createUser>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <name>Batman</name>
   </createUser>
</parameters>
```

I don't know why Soapvar doesn't provide a way to specify attributes. The answer given in this thread [How to add attributes to soapVars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257973/how-to-add-attributes-to-soapvars) doesn't seem to work. The question seems to be doing a lot of rounds:

1: [PHP SoapVar Object Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223896/php-soapvar-object-attribute)

2: [SOAP request with attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327151/soap-request-with-attribute)

But there is no concrete answer yet. Does anyone know the right way to get this done?