# PHP SOAP return array of same name elements with attributes

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to return values the way they are sent into my soap server so they have the same XML structure.

Here is a sample request for multiple policies with various attributes.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="https://customer-soap.example.com/?WSDL">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:SendPoliciesRequestInput>
         <sesid>someid</sesid>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <policy product="product1" company="ges1" polizzenNr="pol1" premium="1" expiry="01.01.2000" info="blabla1"/>
         <policy product="product2" company="ges2" polizzenNr="pol2" premium="2" expiry="02.01.2000" info="blabla2"/>
      </wsdl:SendPoliciesRequestInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In my php code this translates to an object containing a `sesid` and an array of `policy` elements like this: (`print_r($request)`)

```
stdClass Object
(
    [sesid] => someid
    [policy] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product] => product1
                    [company] => ges1
                    [Nr] => pol1
                    [premium] => 1
                    [expiry] => 01.01.2000
                    [info] => blabla1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product] => product2
                    [company] => ges2
                    [Nr] => pol2
                    [premium] => 2
                    [expiry] => 02.01.2000
                    [info] => blabla2
                )
```

When trying to return this exact object back to the caller the following code

```
<php
class Example
{
  public function SendPolicies($request)
  {
    return $request;
  }
}
```

outputs like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="https://customer-soap.example.com/?WSDL">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <wsdl:SendPoliciesRequestOutput>
             <sesid>someid</sesid>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <policy />
          </wsdl:SendPoliciesRequestOutput>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried several approaches including creating `SoapVar` but this would only restructure the objects instead of creating an output that is exactly the same as the input.

Every help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [mounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/749434/mounty) solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894102/8247069

> So not ideal. Another way to do it would be to write the XML yourself:
>
> ```
> $soap->param = new SoapVar("<param attrName='attributeName'>value</param>", XSD_ANYXML);
> ```
>
> I don't like either way, but when you've got a deadline, you go with
>   what works.

The problem seems to be that my code is on the server side, thus (as far as I was able to find out during my research) I am not able to switch into WSDL mode although my server is started using a WSDL.